# Button clicked not received in buttonbox

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I have created a overwrite dialog box as shown below in QT/C++

[image]

here is the code associated:

```
DialogOverwrite::DialogOverwrite(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DialogOverwrite)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QPushButton *YesToAllButton = ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::YesToAll);
    QPushButton *YesButton = ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Yes);
    QPushButton *NoToAllButton = ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::NoToAll);
    QPushButton *NoButton = ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::No);
    QPushButton *CancelButton = ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);

    connect(ui->buttonBox, SIGNAL(clicked(QAbstractButton*)),this,
        SLOT(dialogButton(QAbstractButton*)));
}

DialogOverwrite::~DialogOverwrite()
{
    delete ui;
}

void DialogOverwrite::dialogButton(QAbstractButton* aButton) {
    QDialogButtonBox::StandardButton button = ui->buttonBox->standardButton(aButton);
    switch (button) {
    case QDialogButtonBox::YesToAll:
        OverwriteAction = YES_TO_ALL;
        break;
```

....

I have declared QPushButton *YesToAllButton ... in order to connect to the buttonbox design in the ui and triggered the signal clicked.

The triggered works fine but when trying to catch on which button I have clicked, I receive a "NoButton" instead of YesToAll or any other.

Did I miss something

Thanks

Comment: Why do you get the pointers to the buttons in the constructor if you don't use them anywhere?

Comment: Looks like your roles are not set. Did you bother to check those pointers in the constructor to verify buttons with such roles exist?

Comment: @ddriver to be honest, when doing it it allow me to triggered the clicked. What I'm looking is just opening the overwrite box if the same file is detected and catch the answer "Yes....No.." before continuing

Comment: Again - check your roles. You get `NoButton` when it is not a standard button, which means it doesn't have the appropriate role set. I don't say any other reason it will not work.